# Easy Way To Import A Table from MS SQL Server to Django?

Tags: sql-server, django

Is there good documentation on importing existing tables from MS SQL Server to Django? Some of the table names don't get along with Python *(i.e. # in the column name)*. Eventually data will by brought into the MS SQL Server and need to be pushed to Django. I am using mssql-django.

Comment: You're going to have to recreate the models. You can set table names for the models, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use inspectdb to generate models from exiting databases: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models

Comment: This was very helpful! Have to do a good chunk of cleanup, but that was expected.

Comment: Good to hear. Would be nice if you could accept this answer and give it an upvote :)